# Publishing mutiple nuget packages from a single repository in azure devops

Tags: azure-devops, repository, build-system, azure-artifacts

i'm using Azure Devops and have a repository with multiple projects :

- Core : containing the models the other projects use
- Client : the library that is used by other projects
- Azure : a platform specific implementation

Currently i have a build that packages all 3 projects and pushes them on the Azure artifact feed. However, there is a problem when one of the 3 projects has no changes : the build fails. This is normal since the build tries to push the a package with a version number already in the feed and the feed doesn't allow that.

I see no way to check for package changes or existing version in the feed and ignore the packaging or the push. Is there another way to make it so the projects with no change are not packed/pushed on the feed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [git get changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get%20changes?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) rest api to get which project has changes and then only build these projects that has changes. Suppose your Core projects are in Core folder, Client in Client folder, Azure in Azure Folder.  Please check below example:

```
  - job: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: 'windows-latest'
    steps: 
    - powershell: |
        $url="$(System.CollectionUri)/$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/git/repositories/$(Build.Repository.ID)/commits/$(Build.SourceVersion)/changes?api-version=5.1"
        $result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $(System.AccessToken)"} -Method GET

        $changesFolder = $result.changes | Where-Object{$_.item.gitObjectType -match "tree"} | Select-Object -Property {$_.item.path}

        foreach($path in $changesFolder){
          if($path -match '/Client'){
            echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=Client;isOutput=true]$True"
            break
          }
        }

        foreach($path in $changesFolder){
          if($path -match '/Core'){
            echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=Core;isOutput=true]$True"
            break
          }

        foreach($path in $changesFolder){
          if($path -match '/Azure'){
            echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=Azure;isOutput=true]$True"
            break
          }
        }
      name: MyVariable

    - task: VSBuild@1
      condition: eq(variables['MyVariable.Core'], 'true')
      name: buildCore
      ...
    - task: VSBuild@1
      condition: eq(variables['MyVariable.Azure'], 'true')
      name: buildAzure
      ...
    - task: VSBuild@1
      condition: eq(variables['MyVariable.Client'], 'true')  
      name: buildClient
      ...
```

In above example pipeline, i have a powershell task which calls rest api to get the changed path. Then i define variable `Client` and set its value to true if the Client folder has changes, and do the same for Core and Azure folder.

In the following tasks, i have three VSBuild tasks to build the projects respectively. For each VSbuild task i set a [condtion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) to check if the corresponding variable is true, and will be skipped to run if it is not true. For example, if Azure project does not have changes, then variable Azure will be null and the VSbuild task which builds Azure project will be skipped.

With above pipeline, only these projects that have changes will be built and pushed to your Feed.

Another workaround is to create multiple pipelines(eg. client pipeline, core pipeline, azure pipeline) to build and push different project respectively. And in these pipelines use the [path triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#paths), For below example, in Client pipeline to build Client project. This pipeline will only be triggered if the changes are in Client project.

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - master
  paths:
    include:
    - Client/*
    exclude:
    - Azure/*
    - Core/*
```

Hope above helps!

Comment: This helps a lot. I'm just begining to work with a bit more complex solutions in pipelines and these cases are a real headache for me since i'm a beginner in pipelines and the api. Thanks.